# How can I link PythonKit Library to my Xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-pythonkit

I added the PythonKit github link to my Xcode project. In my version of Xcode (14.3). I can't see library validation like in a lot of the forums. I get this error:

> Python library not found. Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library.

I have python aliased to python3 and when I do `where python3` I get two locations:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Note that this app is for iOS. I am not sure how that would work when I deploy the app. A lot of the forums online seem to be outdated. Any Tips?

Comment: Why do you want to link with python library ? IOS app are made using swift or Objective-C or things like flutter, Kotlin,…

Comment: my project requires the usage of some python 3rd party libraries since I am working with stuff in computer vision, so I will be running a python script on an incoming image.